# 0L or 1L Error in python UPDATE command

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

I try to UPDATE a row in a database table over python but gets an 0L or 1L error. I hope someone could help me with this. INSERT command are working well!

I create a database called "rates" with the columns:

```
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `rate` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `source` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `createdate` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

In python:

```
...
...
sql = "UPDATE rates SET rate =%s WHERE symbol=%s"
rate = "3000.0"
symbol = "dax"
data = (rate,symbol)

cur.execute(sql, data)
...
...
```

I also tried this:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE rates SET rate ='3000.0' WHERE symbol='dax'")
```

or

```
cur.execute(sql,(rate,symbol))
```

What is the correct syntax for an update and what does 0L or 1L means?
Google says its something with long integer?! But why? there is no long in my database its just varchar

Hope someone could help me out!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the error message and/or traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I just find the issue.

After an UPDATE you have to send a commit.

Comment: That would not produce any error. Just no data updates in DB.